# AWS Lambda access to Redshift, S3 and Secrets Manager

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am new to AWS and trying to wrap my head around how I can build a data pipeline using Lambda, S3, Redshift and Secrets Manager.  I have searched the web, read a number of documents/tutorials, yet I am still a bit confused as to how I can configure this properly.

In my stack, Lambda will be the core of the tooling, where lambda will need to call out to external APIs, write/read data to S3, access Secrets Manager and be able to connect to redshift for data loading and querying.

My question.  What do I have for options to configure this setup and allow for lambda to access all of the necessary tools/services?

For context, I have been able to poke around and get most things working, but access to Redshift is what has slowed me down.  If I put the lambda into the same VPC as Redshift (default), I lose access to everything else, so I am not certain as to how to proceed.

Answer (score 1):

> For context, I have been able to poke around and get most things working, but access to Redshift is what has slowed me down. If I put the lambda into the same VPC as Redshift (default), I lose access to everything else, so I am not certain as to how to proceed.

A Lambda running in a VPC does not ever get a public IP address. This causes issues when it tries to access things outside the VPC, such as S3 and Secrets Manager.

There are two ways to fix this access issue:

1. Move the Lambda function to private VPC subnets with a route to a [NAT Gateway](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-nat-gateway.html).
2. Add [VPC Gateways](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/privatelink/aws-services-privatelink-support.html) to your VPC for the AWS services you need.

Since you only need your Lambda function to access other AWS services, and not the Internet, you should add an S3 VPC Gateway, and a Secrets Manager VPC Gateway to your VPC.

Comment: Sorry, I suppose I was clear as mud.  I will need the lambda to call out to the APIs on the internet as part of the ETL flow.  Would you still recommend the lambda inside the VPC?  I was hoping that perhaps I was overlooking a flow where Redshift was opened up to allow lambda and access to data on S3.

Comment: And I am certain, that based on how I am asking the question, the networking bits are very foreign to me.  I understand at a high level the idea of isolation from the public internet, but that's about as far as I go at the moment.

Comment: It has to be in the VPC to access things that are in the VPC (the Redshift server), so yes you need to have the Lambda function inside the VPC. You just need to go with the NAT Gateway solution since you also need it to access things on the public Internet.

Comment: Alternatively you could try rewriting your Lambda function to access Redshift over the Data API https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/data-api.html which can be done without running in the VPC.

Comment: Thanks, I will keep playing around.  A few attempts to go the NAT Gateway route did not work.  My existing Redshift Serverless cluster in my default VPC, and a few resources make it seem like routing all traffic to the gateway in the route table should do it, but no dice.  I appreciate the help, this is on my lack of networking knowledge 100%

Comment: You have to have subnets with an Internet Gateway, and the NAT should be in one of those subnets. Then you need new subnets without an Internet Gateway, and a route to the NAT gateway instead.